# Bootstrap dropdown menu will not open in affix position without scrolling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

I have a problem with the dropdown navigation menu of my web page [here](https://bdferr.github.io/quest-for-glory.html); this is based on the interface of an old video game I particularly like. I have set it up with Bootstrap 3.3.7 with something called an "affix," so that when the user has scrolled down past a certain point, the menu button will appear in a fixed position on the right side of the page, as opposed to its default position in the center. I had previously noticed that in this position, if the user clicked on the button, the menu would not appear unless the user then scrolled up or down. I never figured out why this was.

Now, though, possibly due to a newer version of Bootstrap, clicking on the button and then pressing the up or down arrow does not scroll down. It does make the menu appear, but it does so while jumping back to the top of the page and using a new functionality which allows the user to select a menu item with the arrow keys. Instead of using the down arrows, I can still use the scroll bar after clicking and this still makes the menu appear in the right position. But of course, this is awkward and probably not something most users would think to do.

I just want the dropdown menu to function in the affix position the same way it does in its default position and I am not sure how to do this.

Here is the markup I am using for the button and the menu itself:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="231">
Where to?
<img id="feet-icon" src="feet-icon.png" alt="feet icon" />
            </button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="231">
<li id="li-top" class="othernavbar"><a href="#downloads">Downloads</a></li>
<li class="othernavbar normal"><a href="#images">Game Images</a></li>
<li class="othernavbar normal"><a href="#icons">Icons</a></li>
<li class="othernavbar normal"><a href="#music">Music</a></li>
<li id="li-bottom" class="othernavbar"><a href="https://bdferr.github.io">My Homepage</a></li>
</ul>
```

My stylesheet is [here](https://bdferr.github.io/ferrerih_qfg_stylesheet.css).

I have made sure I have included the reference to jQuery (2.2.4) before the references to Bootstrap in the head of the document.

Comment: You need to apply affix to the parent element that wraps your button and menu `<div class="dropdown offset">`

Comment: Alright, I have just done that so now it looks like this: ```<div class="dropdown offset" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="231">``` but when I test it I see nothing behaving any differently. Do you have any other ideas?